# How can I take screenshots of webpages with Perl?

Tags: perl

Is it possible to write a script in Perl that opens different URLs and saves a screenshot of each of them?

Comment: That would be hard, Perl can't render a webpage for it to save a screenshot.

Comment: Python or any other scripting language?

Comment: @Murali : That doesn't mean you can't use Perl. See my post below.

Comment: Are you just saving a screenshot, or do you plan to manipulate the image?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW::Mechanize::Firefox) to control a Firefox instance and dump the rendered page with `$mech->content_as_png`.

Be aware that setting it up can pose quite a challenge, though.

If all works as expected, you can simply use a script like this to dump images of the desired websites, but you should start Firefox and resize it to the desired width manually (height doesn't matter, WWW::Mechanize::Firefox always dumps the whole page).

```
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
use Path::Class qw/file/;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new(
  bufsize => 10_000_000, # PNGs might become huge
);
$mech->get('http://www.stackoverflow.com/');

my $fh = file( 'test.png' )->open( '> :raw' );
print $fh $mech->content_as_png();
```

Comment: I wrote about this module for PerlTricks: [Controlling Firefox from Perl](http://perltricks.com/article/138/2014/12/8/Controlling-Firefox-from-Perl)

Answer (score 9):

Use the `WWW::Selenium` module, for which you'll need to have a [Selenium Remote Control](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/) session up and running.

The `capture_entire_page_screenshot()` method should get you up and running.

From [WWW::Selenium](http://search.cpan.org/~lukec/Test-WWW-Selenium-1.21/lib/WWW/Selenium.pm) on CPAN:

> `$sel->capture_entire_page_screenshot($filename, $kwargs)`
>
> Saves the entire contents of the current window canvas to a PNG file...

---

A typical script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Selenium;

my $sel = WWW::Selenium->new( host => "localhost", 
                              port => 4444, 
                              browser => "*iexplore", 
                              browser_url => "http://www.google.com",
                            );

$sel->start;
$sel->open("http://www.google.com");
$sel->capture_entire_page_screenshot("screenshot.png");
$sel->close;
```

Answer (score 8):

Another approach, which doesn't require the use of a browser, is to use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) and [HTML2PS](http://user.it.uu.se/~jan/html2ps.html) to convert the image.  Be warned however, this isn't trivial, and it's near impossible (last I tried) to get this working on Windows properly.

Once [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) is installed, the simplest approach is to just run a system call to the `convert` program that [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) installs.  If you want a less hackish approach, you can use the [PerlMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php) [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) API.

There is an excellent discussion on this approach you can find on [PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=Turning%20HTML%20into%20an%20Image).

Answer (score 4):

You could also use [Win32::IE::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::IE::Mechanize) to render the web page using IE, and then [Win32::Screenshot](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::Screenshot) to capture the page.  You'll probably have to do a bit of work to figure out where to take the screenshot, but that shouldn't be too incredibly hard.

This will be a Windows platform only solution, of course, but may suffice.

Comment: Looks like Win32::IE::Mechanize is no longer working with Activestate and/or Windows 7: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Win32-IE-Mechanize but this looks like it still works http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-IEAutomation-0.5/lib/Win32/IEAutomation.pm

Answer (score 3):

Use a third-party web service API like http://webshotspro.com/ (screenshots) or http://www.thumbalizr.com/ (thumbnails).