# Taking screenshot of a webpage programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, screenshot, webpage-screenshot

How do take a sceenshot of a webpage programmatically given the URL as input?

And here is what I have till now:

```
// The size of the browser window when we want to take the screenshot (and the size of the resulting bitmap)
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(1024, 768);
Rectangle bitmapRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1024, 768);
// This is a method of the WebBrowser control, and the most important part
webBrowser1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, bitmapRect);

// Generate a thumbnail of the screenshot (optional)
System.Drawing.Image origImage = bitmap;
System.Drawing.Image origThumbnail = new Bitmap(120, 90, origImage.PixelFormat);

Graphics oGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(origThumbnail);
oGraphic.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
oGraphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
oGraphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
Rectangle oRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 120, 90);
oGraphic.DrawImage(origImage, oRectangle);

// Save the file in PNG format
origThumbnail.Save(@"d:\Screenshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);
origImage.Dispose();
```

But this is not working. It is only giving me a white blank picture. What am I missing here?

Is there any other way I could get the screenshot of a web page programmatically?

Comment: This question was just asked yesterday, although mainly directed at Perl. Maybe some of the answers there would help you, although would obviously take you another direction. Here's the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312852/how-can-i-take-screenshots-with-perl).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I searched and searched and searched and found it *[Webpage thumbnailer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/webpage_thumbnailer.aspx)* (a [The Code Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Code_Project) article).

Comment: This uses Microsofts web browser control which gives you a blank white screenshot frequently

Answer (score 4):

Drawing the browser control to a bitmap is somewhat unreliable. I think it would be better to just screenscrape your window.

```
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapSize.Width, bitmapSize.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    graphics.CopyFromScreen(
        PointToScreen(webBrowser1.Location),
        new Point(0, 0), 
        bitmap.Size);
        bitmap.Save(filename);
}
```

Comment: This approach won't work in Console App, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can try calling the native `PrintWindow` function.

Comment: Can u explain a bit more on this? Please note that I just have the URL of the webpage as input.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try P/Invoking `BitBlt()` from `gdi32.dll`. Try this code:

```
Graphics mygraphics = webBrowser1.CreateGraphics();
Size s = new Size(1024, 768);
Bitmap memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, mygraphics);
Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
IntPtr dc1 = mygraphics.GetHdc();
IntPtr dc2 = memoryGraphics.GetHdc();
// P/Invoke call here
BitBlt(dc2, 0, 0, webBrowser1.ClientRectangle.Width, webBrowser1.ClientRectangle.Height, dc1, 0, 0, 13369376);
mygraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc1);
memoryGraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc2);
memoryImage.Save(filename);
```

The P/Invoke would be:

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
internal static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hdc, int nXDest, int nYDest, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hdcSrc, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, uint dwRop);
```