# Capture image of webbrowser control

Tags: vb.net

I want to capture the image of my webbrowser, or actually just a part of it.

I already achieved it, but it just takes a screenshot of it instead of capturing the bitmap itself.

So when i use this technique and you drag another window above it, the window is also captured. (this is what I don't want.)

My code:

```
' 1. Get the WebBrowsers bitmap.

    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(WebBrowser1.Width, WebBrowser1.Height)
    Dim BMPEndResult As Bitmap
    Dim graph As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
    Dim p As Point = Me.PointToScreen(WebBrowser1.Location)
    graph.CopyFromScreen(p.X, p.Y, 0, 0, bmp.Size)
    picDest.Image = bmp
```

So I need to get the image of the webbrowser:

```
 - without the scrollbars if possible
 - Even if the window is minimized or in the task bar
 - Full webbrowser
 - and also if possible just a part of it, where I can specify the top, left, width and height
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate Screenshot From WebBrowser Control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827373/generate-screenshot-from-webbrowser-control)

Comment: As I said, I do NOT want a screenshot. However thank you for the link.

Comment: C# source code for IECapt is available here: http://iecapt.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

WebBrowser.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, rectangle)

Comment: it says that this method is not supported by this control.