# Screenshot of a URL

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How can I generate a screenshot of a webpage using a server-side script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713938/how-can-i-generate-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-using-a-server-side-script)
>   [Taking screenshot of a webpage programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316564/taking-screenshot-of-a-webpage-programmatically)

How can I make a script in [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) for take a screenshot of a [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator)?

When I take a URL as an input I would lile to get a screenshot for that URL.

Comment: I think you want a screen shot of the webpage at that URL?

Answer (score 1):

A screenshot is taken from a browser. The only way to do this from server-side [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) code is to make a call to a browser that lives on the server, ask it to go to the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator), and ask it to take a screenshot, and place it somewhere or return it over socket.

Instead of a browser standalone EXE file, you could also use a library that you can call from PHP which has HTML rendering capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but i am beginner for PHP can you tell me in detail.

Comment: abhay: the url's provided by Colin Pickard lead you to some resources. Although they do not seem to be cross-platform. My suggestion would be to use existing webservices such as http://browsershots.org/ and pay the necessary penalties that come with using such services

Comment: I downvoted because (a) the original edit suggested the asker was simply confusing server-side and client-side, and I don't agree plus I think that would lead them down the wrong track and (b) the answer seemed way too technical for the asker.

Comment: I have since removed my downvote because I added my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these similar Stack Overflow questions, they might help:

- *[Taking screenshot of a webpage programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316564)*
- *[Programmatically get a screenshot of a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981670)*
- *[How can I generate a screenshot of a webpage using a server-side script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713938)*

Comment: I have voted as well; there is more than one relevant question though, and you can only put one in the close reason.