# Is there any way to run asp.net web browser control on server?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, vb.net

ASP.NET. VB.NET 3.5

In order to scrape image URLs automatically from some of our clients' websites, we want to inspect the DOM after JavaScript has completed running as often the rendered HTML changes because of onload() JavaScript. The article:

[Get the final generated html source using c# or vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14847656/get-the-final-generated-html-source-using-c-sharp-or-vb-net)

shows how to do that with a form with a web browser control on the client but is there a way to do it all on the server (since our process is called in a background thread anyway when the client navigates off a certain aspx page)?

Tia

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688281/webbrowser-class-in-asp-net-website and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307800/view-generated-source-after-ajax-javascript-in-c-sharp addressed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment for other links for a response.