# How can I take a screenshot of website with Perl?

Tags: perl, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I take screenshots with Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312852/how-can-i-take-screenshots-with-perl)

How can I take a screenshot from a site (in batch mode) using Perl? I.e. solution should produce image file (say .png) given an URL. It would be nice, if no X Window system will be required for solution to work.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312852/how-can-i-take-screenshots-with-perl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW::Mechanize::Firefox). Unfortunately it does need X (at least on non-OS X *NIX), but you can use xvfb to run it headless.

Answer (score 2):

In the past I needed to convert a web page to PDF.
I used http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ and it worked *beautifully* (it's using the excellent WebKit engine). Problem is it's not Perl-based and it doesn't produce an image, but a PDF. Try it, it might suit your needs (` No longer requires an XServer to be running (however the X11 client libs must be installed' )

Answer (score 1):

If your going to go beyond screen shots, finding a binding for [Watir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watir) would be my advice. The ability to get javascript, java/flash/activex embedd scripting working is nice (for some value of nice)