# Taking Screenshot in perl

Tags: linux, perl, screenshot

i am running a perl script from a linux machine to log onto a router remotely to collect data. few of my client requirements include screenshots of specific configs.
i tried using

```
Imager::Screenshot
```

But each time it is printing a black screen. Is there a better way to capture screenshots of the router output, rather capturing the screenshot of the  linux screen would work well for me as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: perhaps this is helpful - getting WWW::Mechanize::Firefox to display webpage image: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312852/how-can-i-take-screenshots-of-webpages-with-perl

Comment: Are you connecting to the router via a GUI or CLI?

Comment: i'd guess that your router has no X (or something equivalent) running, hence you aren't able to shoot at a screen that isn't there.

Comment: am connected via cli. If X is not running, is there a method of getting a screenshot of the screen?

Comment: could anyone point to a soultion or suggest a method to fulfill the task.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this coding:

```
sub new {
    my $class  = shift;
    my @params = ();
    @params = @{shift()} if _ARRAY0($_[0]);
    my $image = Imager::Screenshot::screenshot( @params );
    unless ( _INSTANCE($image, 'Imager') ) {
    Carp::croak('Failed to capture screenshot');
    }

    # Hand off to the parent class
    return $class->SUPER::new( image => $image, @_ );
}
```

give thanks to: [Taking Screenshot in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983765/taking-screenshot-in-perl)

Comment: this sub is giving a black screen as well.