# How to write a Perl script to take screenshots of a website's different pages and mail it?

Tags: perl, webpage-screenshot

I wanted to take screenshots of different pages of our internal websites and mail it to someone on weekly basis. I tried in Perl however I do not see any relevant modules which can help in this. please suggest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I take screenshots of webpages with Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312852/how-can-i-take-screenshots-of-webpages-with-perl)

Comment: Oh another *"Did not work"* error message. We're seeing these so often I think there must be a fundamental error in the basics of computer science that affects all software on all machines.

Comment: @Borodin as I said below, I think this needs hammering. Would you do the honors?

Comment: @simbabque: Sorry, I don't have a hammer with me. Voted to close instead.

Comment: You could look into a Perl driver for PhantomJS - I've done this in PHP and it works very well.

Comment: @halfer: [WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS#mech-content_as_png-coordinates) also has `content_as_png` method :)

Answer (score 1):

> i tried in Perl however i do not see any relevant modules which can
>    help in this

There are plenty. Did you even try to search it on CPAN? A simple search containing "[screenshot](https://metacpan.org/search?size=20&q=screenshot&search_type=modules)" as search string.

Did you search about it on StackOverflow itself? See the below question which lists many ways to do it.

[How can I take screenshots of webpages with Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312852/how-can-i-take-screenshots-of-webpages-with-perl)

Simplest approach would be to use [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW::Mechanize::Firefox) module's `$mech->content_as_png` method.

> mail it to someone on weekly basis

Again, there are plenty of [Email::](https://metacpan.org/search?q=Email%3A%3A&search_type=modules) modules available on CPAN. Pick the one you like.

Comment: You should have voted to close as duplicate. I just voted to close as off-topic so now I cannot hammer any more.

Comment: @simbabque: Yes, did that.

Comment: It's off topic, but actually I quite like it when we reach out to educate users on how to search first. Thanks Chankey.